# ubuntu installation on minix neo x5

Tags: system-installation

I have a mini pc "Minix Neo X5" running Android on it. I would like to install Ubuntu on it. It has RK3066 chip I guess. I am not a geek, but I can understand installation procedure. Is there any version/form of Ubuntu available for this kind of pc system ?

Raj

Answer (score 1):

You can try Picuntu: http://ubuntu.g8.net/
It's an Ubuntu distro specialized for Rockchip based computers like Neo X5 and X7.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the procedure described at http://cobecoballes-embedded.blogspot.nl/2014/02/minix-neo-x5-booting-in-linuxubuntu.html. I followed it and managed to get it up and running with the Gnome desktop, although it wouldn't run Unity.